# Vim: Reverse selection

Tags: vim

If my line looks like this:

```
abcdefghi
```

How can I reverse the selected characters (for example: from position 2 to position 6 (5 characters)) to get the result like this:

```
a(fedcb)ghi
```

And how can I yank, reverse and paste somewhere else to get the result like this:

```
abcdefghi(fedcb)
```

NB: parentheses used only for visualization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `'revins'` option to do this, as suggested [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Reverse_selected_text):

```
vnoremap <f4> c<C-O>:set ri<CR><C-R>"<Esc>:set nori<CR>
```

If you want to paste it somewhere else, yank it as you otherwise do and use this "reverse paste" mapping:

```
nnoremap <f4> :set ri<cr>i<C-r>"<Esc>:set nori<cr>
```

Comment: ´revins´ should solve my problem, but I am getting ´"E481: No range allowed"´.

Comment: @Poe, use `:<C-u>` to get rid of the range.