# How can I reverse selection in VsVim?

Tags: vim, vsvim

I want to reverse selected text in VsVim in VS2022.

For instance: `asdfg` to `gfdsa`

I have tried [Reverse selected text](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Reverse_selected_text) and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726126/vim-reverse-selection).
But these measures made my selection replaced by `c`. If I secelct the text visually first, and type `:set revins`, I will get an error: `No range allowed`.

Is there any neat way to reverse selection?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vim: Reverse selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726126/vim-reverse-selection)

Comment: @robni, It works  in Vim, not in VsVim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using Vim. You are using a partial re-implementation of Vim so there is no reason whatsoever to expect anything that works in Vim to work the same in that extension.

Case in point, VsVim doesn't support the `revins` option so there is no point in even trying random internet solutions that depend on it. Moreover, VsVim doesn't support vimscript either so a working Vim-only solution like:

```
c<C-r>=split(@",'\zs')->reverse()->join('')<CR>
```

is useless to you.